# pass by reference but the value of parameter is null

Tags: c, function, struct, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I am programming in C.

I have a struct:

```
 struct MY_TYPE {
      boolean flag;
      short int value;
      double stuff;
    };
```

I have a function which takes a pointer to pointer of `MY_TYPE` as parameter:

```
getData(struct MY_TYPE ** m_type) {
  // I initialise an object of MY_TYPE
  struct MY_TYPE a = {.value = 123};
  // I assign the address of above object to a pointer of MY_TYPE
  struct MY_TYPE *p = &a;
  // I assign the address of above pointer to parameter
  m_type = &p;
}
```

In my main program, I call the above function:

```
struct MY_TYPE *my_param;
getData(&my_param);

// I set a break pointer here, and it shows me my_param is NULL, why?
```

After I called getData(...), the parameter I passed in is NULL, why?

Comment: Do you know something about local scoped var.....

Comment: Whatever, variable 'a' is local to getData() function, so you must not return it (or a pointer to it, or worse a pointer to a pointer which is also a local variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a would-be undefined behavior, which does not happen because you are assigning a pointer passed by value.

- Any changes that you make to `m_type` inside `getData` are ignored by the caller. You need to assign `*m_type` in order for the change to make any difference.
- With this change in place, you would start getting undefined behavior, because `struct a` goes out of scope as soon as `getData` returns.

You can fix this by returning a dynamically allocated block initialized inside your function:

```
getData(struct MY_TYPE ** m_type) {
  // I initialize an object of MY_TYPE
  struct MY_TYPE a = {.value = 123};
  // I make a copy into dynamic memory
  struct MY_TYPE *copy = malloc(sizeof(struct MY_TYPE));
  memcpy(copy, &a);
  // I assign the address of above pointer to parameter
  *m_type = copy;
}
```

The caller needs to free the memory received from the call:

```
struct MY_TYPE *my_param;
getData(&my_param);
... // Use my_param here.
// Now that I am done with my_param...
free(my_param);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a local variable, the lifetime of this variable ends with the function, use `malloc` in order to preserve his value.

```
struct MY_TYPE *p = malloc(sizeof *p);

if (p != NULL) {
    p->value = 123;
    *m_type = p; /* Dereference the passed pointer to pointer */
}
```